# Given an array how to remove items that aren't included in a textarea value (string)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with the following when console.log(cMentions):

```
Object
41: "Never Ever"
43: "Steve Jobs"
55: "Henry Ford"
__proto__: Object
```

Then I have a textarea(id="comment") with:

```
Hello @Steve Jobs @Never Ever and friends
```

What I want to do is determine if the cMentions record are in the textarea value. If they are do X, if they are not do Y.

Use case. When this runs, it would notice that Henry Ford is not in the textarea and would remove it.

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each element, and check whether the name at the key exists in the string, using `.indexOf`:

```
//cMentions is defined as in the question
var commentValue = $('#comment').val();
for (var id in cMentions) {
    if (cMentions.hasOwnProperty(id)) { // Ignore native methods
        var searchTerm = cMentions[id]; // Search for the existence of this name
        if (commentValue.indexOf(searchTerm) == -1) {
            cMentions[id] = void 0;     // Overwriting by `void 0` = `undefined`
            delete cMentions[id];       // In case the variable still exists
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good but that makes the array item like so: 19: undefined --- How can I actually get rid of the record in the array

Comment: @RachelaMeadows At my browser, `19` disappears as an entry. I've updated the answer in case it doesn't, using `delete`.

Comment: Why would you ever set something to `void 0`?  If you want `undefined`, can't you just set something to `undefined`?  In this case, it seems that only the `delete` operator is needed.  There's no need for the `void 0` assignment.

Comment: @jfriend00 Unlike `null`, `undefined` can be overwritten by an arbitrary value. `var undefined = 1; alert(undefined)` shows `1`, rather than `undefined`. Replace `undefined` by `null`, and you get an error.

Comment: Lots of stuff can be replaced in JS.  Maybe you worry about that if you're writing a widely used JS library that has to coexist with zillions of other scripts, but why waste time worrying about that in your own page JS where you control what's in the page?  By that logic, I should be afraid of using `Array.indexOf()` because it might be changed too.

Comment: @jfriend00 `void 0` is not only more correct, but also shorter than `undefined`. Following the logic, I don't have to fear that `Array.indexOf` is overwritten, because it's very unlikely that you write `Array.prototype.indexOf = 1;` by accident.

Comment: I'm not sure where you get "more correct" from.  I'll stick with setting something to `null` or `undefined` if need be (usually I use `null`) because that seems a lot more readable and has always worked.  In this case, it isn't need at all.  Just use the `delete` line which is even more readable IMO.